# How to get Google definition search in other languages?

Tags: google-search, localization

The previous version of Google's `definition:` search, showed some language options, so I could lookup the definition of a term in other languages. But since they updated it, I can't find those options anymore. Is there anyway to reach them?

Comment: `definition:` is no longer a search operator. Google Search has moved from working based primarily on keywords to working based on structured data and Knowledge Graph. Learn about this at https://blog.google/ and https://support.google.com/websearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been changed. You have to change the search language in order to see the other definitions—if the word exists in the chosen language.

In english:

[image]

To see definitions in other languages, click on the cog wheel in the upper-right corner, and choose **Languages**.

[image]

Choose the language and click **Save**.

[image]

Now the definition will be shown for the chosen language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this is how they changed it: First, you look up the definition using `definition:` or `define:` and if you click on ">>More" link placed next to the result, the definiton page opens. At the lower right corner, there is a box called **Related Languages** (it says: *this term* is also a word in ...). So when you click on one of them, you can see the definition in that language. For example:

`define:auto`

[image]